# Does this basic property of hyperreal function hold?

Tags: analysis, filters, nonstandard-analysis

Let $x=(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...) + \mathcal U  \in {}^\ast \mathbb R := \displaystyle\prod_1^\infty \mathbb R/\mathcal U$ be a hyperreal number [using the ultrapower construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ultrapower#definition) and $f \colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a real function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.
We can extend $f$ via the transfer principle to ${}^\ast f \colon {} ^\ast\mathbb R \to {} ^\ast \mathbb R$. Also, let ${}^\ast x:= {} ^\ast f(x)$.

Will we have ${}^\ast x=(f(a_1), f(a_2), f(a_3), ...) + \mathcal U \in {}^\ast \mathbb R$? That is, does ${}^\ast$ "respect" applying $f$ pointwise to every coordinate of ${}^\ast x$?

I don't see how this immediately follows from the transfer principle.

Comment: Alas, this question needs some work. The function ${}^\ast\!f$ maps equivalence classes of sequences to equivalence classes of sequences. It makes no sense to ask whether ${}^\ast\!f$  respects "pointwise" equality. The elements of the codomain of ${}^\ast\!f$ are equivalence classes, they *do not have* a notion of pointwise equality in the first place!

Comment: @Z.A.K. I of course mean the *class* it belongs to (sorry for the abuse of notation). We usually just represent a class with a representative to that class. Any representative equal a.e. would belong to the same class.

Comment: I quite don't understand meaning of the question.  If $f$ is a real function, and $x$ is a equivalence class of $a_n$, then (if  $x$ doesn't correspond to some real number) it would have no sense to $*f(x)=x$. If $*f(x)=x$ then $*f$ fulfill $\exists x\forall y *f(x)=y$ so there is a real number $r$ such that $f(x)=r$

Comment: @Antares Maybe we can sort out what the confusion is, then! $x$ is a hyperreal number and $f$ a real-valued function defined on $\mathbb R$. The function ${}^\ast f$ is the hyperreal extension of $f$, and ${}^\ast f$ both takes and spits out hyperreal numbers. The numbers $a_n$ are real numbers, so $f(a_n)$ are real numbers too. Thus, $(f(a_n))_n$ is a sequence of real numbers. This sequence is a representative of some hyperreal number, let call it $w$. The question is then whether ${}^\ast x = w$ or not.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver $(f(a _n))$ isn't representation of some hyperreal. It's equivalenve classes of real sequences are some hyperreals, it's significant difference.  So the case is wheter  $[( f( a_i))]=^*f(x)$? The definition of $^*f([ (a _i)])$ is $^*f([(a_i)])=[(F_i)]$ where $F_i=f(a_i)$, so yes, for hyperreal number $x=[(a_i)]$, we got $^*f(x)=[(f( a _i))]$.    By  $[(a_i)]$ I mean $[(a_i)]_\sim$ where $(a_i)\sim (b_i)\iff \{i ∈ \mathbb{N}: a_i=b_i\}\in\mathscr{U}$

Comment: @Antares A representative to me is an element of an equivalence class. So in general, $a$ is a representative for the class $[a]$. The question is then if ${}^\ast f([(a_n)_n]) = [\left(f\left((a_n)\right)\right)_n]$.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver Yes. I Answered in previous comment that $^* f(x)=[(f(a _i))_i]$ for $x=[(a_i)_i]$.  In general for $n$-ary function $f$, we got  $^*f([(a_{1,i})_i],[(a_{2,i})_i],...,[(a_{n,i})_i])=[(f( a_{1,i},a_{2,i},...,a_{n,i}))_i]$, where $a_{j,i}$ are real sequences. I suggest to look at definition of ultraproduct, it's direct implication of how ultraproducts are defined how the function will looks like.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ultraproduct.html  Here is a definition of ultraproduct. Ultrapower is special case when   $(\mathbb{A_i})$ is constant sequence (in our case of hyperreals,   $I=\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{A}=^*\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{A}_i=\mathbb{R}$ for any $i$).